# Save a dropdown list into database

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a list which is displayed from my database:

```
<<b>List</b>
                <?php
            $select = "SELECT * FROM quabits.inregistrare";
            $result2 = mysql_query($select);
            ?>
        <form id="raport" name="save">
            <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
             <tr><td>Selectează:&nbsp;</td>
             <td><select name="den" id="den" onchange="rulare(this.value)">
             <option value="">Selectați un profesor</option>
            <?php 
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
            echo "<option value='" . $row['Email'] ."'> " .$row['Nume'] ." ". $row['Prenume'] ."</option>";
            }?>
            </select>
            </td></tr>
          </table>
</form>
<input id="save" name="save"  type="submit" value="Submit" action="POST"/>
```

After the drop down menu I put a button to submit.

And after a value is selected and click for submit, I want to save into my database (quabits table inregistrare) the value.
Here I'm lost. Any help ?

Comment: Use an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a select like the following:

```
<select name="den" id="den" onchange="rulare(this.value)">
    <option value="">Selectați un profesor</option>
     .....
</select>
```

You would retrieve the value of the select using `$_REQUEST['den']`.

Make sure you add the method type to your form, for example

```
<form id="raport" name="save" method="POST">
```

in PHP you would store the POST value:

```
$den = $_POST['den'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$den = $_POST['den'];
 $link = mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database",3306
 $sql = "Insert into table ('fieldname') VALUES ('$den');
 mysqli_query($link,$sql);`

Very basic solution, but i the question is not very understandable....